# kubuntu grub console at startup

Tags: grub, startup, kubuntu

I neweblie linux user. I have installed `kubuntu` on my laptopn. Every time I see `grub` console at the startup. Console does not exit by timeout. I must to input `"exit"`. How to disable `grub` console on startup?

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust **grub 2** 's behaviour, you can edit this configuration file `/etc/default/grub` and commit your changes using this command : `sudo update-grub`.

> The GRUB documentation is here :
> http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html

Beware !
Before disabling the grub menu and console at boot, you need to ensure that your system can boot automatically on your preferred system ! If you have installed linux over (after) windows as a dual boot, you can adjust the default boot option in `/etc/default/grub` thru the key `GRUB_DEFAULT` (the default is `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` then you can set `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` )
and commit your changes by `sudo update-grub`.

**When you are sure that your system is able to boot automatically, you can decide to remove the menu and/or the console or change their behaviours.**

In order to shorten the menu's display duration you can adjust this option : `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
and commit your changes by `sudo update-grub`.

In order to hide the menu you need to change this option : `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`
by : `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`

In order to remove the console you need to comment this line : `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
by inserting `#` at the beginning of the line : `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`

*PS :

If you have 2 systems and still need to choose your boot, consider also the usage of `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`

If you want to see the linux kernel messages when it boots (instead of the splash screen logo) you can switch the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`.*